# Not able to edit datasource in Sitecore content & experience editor in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

I am having a issue. The datasource editing seems to disabled for a particular role "Regional Content Author" but is enabled for another in sitecore content & experience editor.

I have analyzed that both the roles have read & write ability for the items (for which we want the datasource to be edited) in the Access Viewer.

Can someone suggest what may the issue?

PFB the screenshot: [image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot what happens when you want to edit datasource? Is it `Edit datasource` icon missing? Field disabled? Some other issue? Have you checked "Write" access rights for the `Datasource` field?

Comment: Also, answering your question, the edit Datasource field is disabled. However, the user & role both have "Write" access to the datasource field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I figured out what the issue was.

Adding the predefined role Sitecore/Designer gave the necessary permissions to edit Datasource.

I am currently looking how to assign the permissions without assigning any pre-existing roles